# Http 404 when accessing a document over SSL

Tags: iis, ssl, iis7

I am trying to use the below code to download and read the bytes of a document using System.NET.WebClient class. The file is in a SharePoint document library and the web application is using SSL. The code throws the exception 404 not found when executing the last line below.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
webClient.DownloadData("https://sharepointwebsite/document-library/Test.docx");
```

The program is running in the context of System Account user and if I try to access the above URL in the browser it works and downloads the file. What settings do I need to do in IIS or in my code for it to work? This works on a separate box for the same website but without SSL.

Thanks !

Comment: Does your SharePoint work on http? If yes, try the `DownloadData` method with http and see if it works? This is to make sure the issue is with https or http.